# Run-Time Error '9': subscript out of range with WorksheetFunction

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I'm trying to write a simple code to look at a data input section and add that data into an existing data table. The number of rows I want to copy changes every time so I attempted to make the array capable of adjusting size to suit.

```
Dim size As Integer
Dim new_resources() As String
Dim i as Integer

size = worksheetfunction.CountA("E:E") - 1
**ReDim new_resources(size)**
i=1
For i to size
    new_resources(i) = cells(i+1,5)
Next i
```

I get the following error:

> Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range.

on the line marked with **.

Comment: I would probably approach this differently - instead of making new_resources an array of strings, why not make it simply a Range? And then define the range as E1:E[size]? Then iterate through the rows or copy the whole thing at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting that error on your `ReDim` line, it must mean that `size` is less than zero, which must mean that `COUNTA("E:E")` is returning zero. You may want to assert that `size >= 0` before attempting to `ReDim` your array. For example:

```
size = worksheetfunction.CountA("E:E") - 1

If size < 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error! No rows found in column E."
Else
    ReDim new_resources(size)
End If
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what was happening now to figure out why the countA function isn't registering the information in the sheet.

Comment: See @Jeeped's answer. You need to use `worksheetfunction.CountA(Range("E:E")) - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays start with 0 not 1.  So Change your new_resources(i) to new_resources(i-1).

Comment: Good catch! This is why I always prefer `For i = [LBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a7w1ac(v=vs.90).aspx)(new_resources) to [UBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278658.aspx)(new_resources).

Answer (score 1):

That's not how the [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx) works. On the worksheet, that is sufficient to pass in a cell range but not in VBA.

```
Dim sz As Long
Dim new_resources() As String
Dim i as Integer

sz = worksheetfunction.CountA(Range("E:E")) - 1
ReDim new_resources(sz)
i=1
For i to sz
    new_resources(i) = cells(i+1, 5)
Next i

'alternates
sz = worksheetfunction.CountA(Columns(5)) - 1
sz = worksheetfunction.CountA(Cells(1, 5).EntireColumn) - 1
```

You need to reference one or more cells on a worksheet like you do in other VBA operations. The lack of a parent worksheet worries me; maybe you should address that as well.

Comment: I only posted the excerpt of the code that was giving me a problem. There is quite a bit more to the entire macro  than what I posted. All my experience with macros is self-taught and so most of what I do is not necessarily the best way to do things or at times the right way to do things.

Comment: I didn't take it that way at all. I was just trying to let you know the 'why' behind my crappy coding :)